# Generating WebAssembly from a library linking opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, emscripten

So I have a CMake C++ project which generates a library for other parts of the system. Internally, it uses OpenCV. Everything's working fine except when I try to compile it with emscripten for generating WebAssembly.
The OpenCV part is starting to complain about:

```
opencv2/core/hal/intrin_wasm.hpp:2917:1: error: always_inline function 'wasm_v128_load' requires target feature 'simd128', but would be
inlined into function 'v_load' that is compiled without support for 'simd128'
```

There are more than 20 errors such as this one all over this header file.

I am generating this library in a docker using following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
    
ARG EMSDK_VESION=1.40.1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
    
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y cmake make tree git clang g++ libtbb-dev python && \
    apt clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
    
RUN git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git && cd emsdk && \
    ./emsdk install $EMSDK_VESION && \
    ./emsdk activate $EMSDK_VESION && \
    cd .. && chmod +x emsdk/*.sh
    
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
    
RUN mkdir -p linux && cd linux && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/out && make install
RUN bin/build-fe.sh
    
RUN tree /out
```

where build-fe.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /emsdk/emsdk_env.sh

mkdir -p frontend && cd "$_" 
emcmake cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make -j 16
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try `emmake make` instead of `make -j 16`. I don't know how much of a difference it makes, but I have gotten strange errors that were easily solved by taking out the `-j` make flag.

Comment: Dou you really need ALL of OpenCV? I have a similar scenario, where I use OpenCV in a project that I compile with emscripten. I had to disable a lot of options to get it to work. Fortunately, I did not need those options ;-)